# How add list post title wordpress in table?

Tags: php, wordpress

How add list post title wordpress in table

I have code in index.php wp theme like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @WP-Theme Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>
    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php if ( function_exists( 'page_navi' ) ) page_navi( 'items=7&prev_label=Prev&next_label=Next&first_label=First&last_label=Last&show_num=1&num_position=after' ); ?><br/>
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div><a class="judul" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a> 
    <small><div style="text-indent: 10px;">Oleh: <?php the_tags(' '); ?> | Media: <?php the_category(', '); ?> | Terbit: <?php the_time('l, j F Y'); ?> | Dibaca: <?php if(function_exists('the_views'))  { the_views(); }?></div></small>
    </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
<br/><?php if ( function_exists( 'page_navi' ) ) page_navi( 'items=7&prev_label=Prev&next_label=Next&first_label=First&last_label=Last&show_num=1&num_position=after' ); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) :
            // Show a different message to a logged-in user who can add posts.
            ?>
            <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No posts to display', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php printf( __( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%s">Get started here</a>.', 'twentytwelve' ), admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ); ?></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <?php else :
            // Show the default message to everyone else.
            ?>
            <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
            </header>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->
        <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This result in frontpage:

[image]

I want add list post title wordpress in table like this:

[image]

What code and where I put its?

Comment: Please carefully read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then visit **ALL** your previous posts and accept the answers to **ALL** your question which solved your perticular issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border="1">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <tr><td colspan="2"><a class="judul" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Oleh: <?php the_tags(' '); ?> | Media: <?php the_category(', '); ?> | Terbit: <?php the_time('l, j F Y'); ?> | Dibaca: <?php if(function_exists('the_views'))  { the_views(); }?></td></tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

You may need to change while loop with above code.

1. create a `<table>` tag before starting while loop and close `</table>` after while loop.
2. create `<tr>` in while loop and `<td>` as per your need.

Comment: Your welcome, waiting for accept @PUSTAKAKORAN.COM :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to style the list.

I suggest using a an unordered list to list your post links in this instance:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php if ( function_exists( 'page_navi' ) ) page_navi( 'items=7&prev_label=Prev&next_label=Next&first_label=First&last_label=Last&show_num=1&num_position=after' ); ?><br/>
<ul>
  <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <li>
    <a class="judul" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </li>
<?php  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
```

You can style accordingly:

```
ul {
list-style-type:none;
border: 2px solid #BCE1F1;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
background: #95DBFE;
}
```

The nth-child selector above will give every odd numbered list item a different style, depending on what declarations you use. In my example, I gave every odd numbered list item a light blue background.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank Skywentysix. It's very nice.

Comment: Happy to help. Hope you found the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

Please do it like this:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #95DBFE;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #BCE1F1;
}
```

Comment: Thank Atif Tariq. It's very helpfull for spesific table.

Comment: @PUSTAKAKORAN.COM Welcome. Appreciated if you choose my answer as best. Thanks